# How do I update existing autowired properties when inserting a new bean?

Tags: java, spring, groovy

We have component classes that autowire beans of a certain type:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {
    @Autowire
    public IValidators[] validators;
}
```

Our application allows the creation of Groovy classes that get compiled at runtime and are registered with Spring using ScriptFactoryPostProcessor:

```
ConstructorArgumentValues args = new ConstructorArgumentValues();
args.addGenericArgumentValue(groovySourceLocation); //location is on the file system
RootBeanDefinition def = new RootBeanDefinition(GroovyScriptFactory.class, args, null);
BeanDefinitionRegistry r = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) this.applicationContext.getBeanFactory();
r.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, def); //beanName is the same as the class name

//scriptFactoryPostProcessor is autowired into class from applicationConfig
scriptFactoryPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(GroovyScriptFactory.class, beanName);
```

The groovy bean is created correctly as I can retrieve it from the applicationContext by the bean name or by the type. But the already autowired properties of components do not have the added bean. When the groovy class implements IValidator, I'd like any component classes that autowire IValidator types to be updated with new groovy bean added to the collection. How do I do this?

**UPDATE**

After looking through the source, I don't see anyway that Spring supports my expectation. My last hope was that I could ask for dependent beans of a type (similar to [getDependentBeans(String beanName)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableBeanFactory.html#getDependentBeans%28java.lang.String%29)) but it does not exist and from the looks of things, Spring does not track dependencies based on type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really interesting question. The easiest approach: make `MyComponent` prototype and create new instance every time you need it. This way Spring will perform autowiring with most recent list of `IValidator` instances. Consider `<lookup-method/>`.

Less elegant way to do this is to have a factory (**not** a `FactoryBean`) that will retrieve all beans implementing `IValidator` on demand and simply call this factory whenever you need it. Sure, not in the Spring spirit at all.

Other approaches are much more cumbersome and error-prone. You might create your own post-processor to add newly discovered `IValidator` to all classes that require list of all of them. You might also develop your own implementation of `List<IValidator>` that will lookup `ApplicationContext` each time requested - a bit challenging, especially when concurrency is taken into account.

Finally there is a *Composite* design pattern: have only one `IValidator` that will delegate all calls to the list of target `IValidator`s discovered manually in `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: I was hoping there was a Spring answer to this that I somehow missed because I wanted to avoid the scenarios you described. Mainly, because of the dynamic nature of our program, the situation I described can occur for other components and bean types, not just my pseudo-code example. Having to code around the limitation reduces the dynamic capabilities of the app.

Comment: Your problem seems like a very interesting feature. If you care, file an [issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR), it might appear some day.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `InitializingBean`.  If you do Spring will call `afterPropertiesSet()` after wiring dependencies.  You could add any special logic to override these dependencies.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html#afterPropertiesSet()

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I have to know all of the components in the Spring universe that have an IValidators collection being set by Spring. I want to avoid tracking that information and just let Spring update for me.